# Is the algorithm for determining if an $N\times N$ ($15$) puzzle is solvable the same as $M \times N$?

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

Most of the algorithms I've seen discuss $N\times N$ grids only.

This is the [method](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html) I'm talking about:

> An inversion is when a tile precedes another tile with a lower number on it. The solution state has zero inversions. ... To explain it another way, an inversion is a pair of tiles (a,b) such that a appears before b, but a>b. Count the number of inversions in the grid. ...
>
> The formula says:
>
> 1. If the grid width is odd, then the number of inversions in a solvable situation is even.
> 2. If the grid width is even, and the blank is on an even row counting from the bottom (second-last, fourth-last etc), then the number of inversions in a solvable situation is odd.
> 3. If the grid width is even, and the blank is on an odd row counting from the bottom (last, third-last, fifth-last etc) then the number of inversions in a solvable situation is even.

There's one [article](http://kevingong.com/Math/SixteenPuzzle.html#proof) I read that discusses $M\times N$ grids but I'm not a math expert so I'm not really sure if the $N\times N$ algorithm applies to $M\times N$.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not describing the algorithms you've seen, it we can't say for sure whether *they* can be applied to non-square puzzles.

In most cases I can't imagine that will be a problem, though -- you can adapt existing algorithms to solve a single row at a time until you have only a square at the end left, and then ignore the rows you have already solved while you solve the final square.

The *general* theory of sliding puzzles applies just fine to non-square puzzles: The usual checkerboard argument shows that only positions that are *even* permutations can be solved, and as long as each of the sides is at least 2 tiles long, one can prove that *all* even permutations can be solved.

Your favorite concrete *method* may or may not depend on having more space to work with than just two rows, though.

---

**After edit:** The rule you quote works no matter whether the height and width are equal.

However, it is rather more convolutedly phrased than I would prefer. We can give a rule that doesn't look like it's full of special cases by:

1. When you count inversions, pretend the empty space is a tile with a higher number than any others.
2. Count the distance between the empty space and the lower-right cell, following the grid lines. For example in a 15-puzzle with the empty space at the far upper left this distance would be $6$ because you need to go $3$ right, $3$ down.
3. The configuration is solvable if and only if the number of inversions *plus* the empty-space distance from the lower right is an *even* number.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added the algorithm I'm talking about.

Comment: @dork: Answer updated.

Comment: #2 is much easier to understand. Thank you! Lifesaver! 